# sed command to consider first 10 digits from last coloumn

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file for eg  with three coloumns

```
12345678910 14567855858855 12345678510750078
```

I want to consider only first 10 digits from the third coloumn with sed or awk.

expected ouput is:

1234567851

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
awk '{ print $3; }' subject.txt | sed -n 's/\([0-9]\{10\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: or `awk '{print substr($3,1,10)}' subject.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This *sed* command will give you the first 10 digits of the last column.
Your question is a bit confused in terms of first or last 10 or 14 digits `:-)`
But, you can adjust likewise on this example.

```
$ echo "12345678910 14567855858855 12345678510750078" \ 
| sed -n 's/.*\s\([0-9]\{10\}\)[0-9]*$/\1/ p'

1234567851
```

Interpreting the command (so you can modify as required).

```
 sed -n 's/.*\s\([0-9]\{10\}\)[0-9]*$/\1/ p'
     |   | | | | |          | |       |   ^ print what remains on the matched line
     |   | | | | |          | |       ^^ replace the line with the part of interest
     |   | | | | |          | ^^^^^^^ match for the last column
     |   | | | | |          ^^ mark the end of part we want to print
     |   | | | | ^^^^^^^^^^^ this will match 10 digits at the start of the last column
     |   | | | ^^ start marking the part we want to print
     |   | | ^ start matching the digits after a white-space char
     |   | ^^ pattern begins matching everything up to the part of interest
     |   ^ process only lines that match the given pattern
     ^^ do not print the original input string
```

You can fine tune this for your data.
As it stands, because of the `[0-9]*$` part in this rule your data is expected to have no whitespace or non-numeric characters after or inside the last column.

**Update on your comment.**
While this example uses an echo of your single line to demonstrate your test-case,
You can fire the command on your entire file as follows,

```
cat input-file.txt | <sed-command-above> > output-file.txt
```

or

```
<sed-command-above> input-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

The first form shows how an `echo` will work for the whole multi-line file too.
You could also do a short test with a `head input-file.txt` piped to the sed command to see how it works on the first 10 lines of you input file.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but my file has some 100 lines. the one line i have given as a sample.. so please give me the sed command to get the first 10 digits of last coloumn not with echo..

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i run this command  sed -n 's/.*\([0-9]\{10\}\)[0-9]*$/\1/ p' inputfile.txt i am not getting any output

Comment: when i run with this sed command  sed -r  's/.*(.{10})$/\1/' 1.csv i am getting the output but it is considering the last 10 digits from the third coloumn i am gettng output as 510750078 for my input file 12345678910 14567855858855 12345678510750078

Comment: Right, my bad, a space in the rule got lost while editing... I've changed that to a `\s` which is more appropriate and easier to not-lose.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'print /(\d{10})\d*$/' < filename
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` adds newlines to output
- `$` matches the end of line, the first 10 digits preceding any other digits before the end are captured, and `/.../` in the list context imposed by `print` returns that

Comment: thanks for that but it is considering the last digits from reverse order.. i am supposed to get  1234567851 but the output gives 510750078

Comment: @ltps: Oh, so you want the **first** ten digits of the last column! You should always add the expected output to a question to make it clearer. Answer updated.

Comment: yes i want the first ten digits of the last column. sorry for that.. will be clear from now on

Answer (score 0):

if you wand sed only solution, try:

```
cat /tmp/textfile |  sed -n -e '$!d;s/.*\s\([0-9]\{10\}\)[0-9]*$/\1/ p'
```

the substitute worked only on the last line.